# can't port forward to application in HAProxy

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, port, haproxy, forward

I have a an application running on port 8000 of www.example.com with 
http://www.example.com:8000/myapp but I want anyone accessing the website to be able to just type till the port number 8000 and the /myapp can automatically be forwarded to... so when i type www.example.com:8000 and hit enter, it should open http://www.example.com:8000/myapp.
how can i achieve this through HAProxy configuration?

Comment: Have you attempted to create an HAProxy configuration?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have configured the haproxy and it listens on port 8000 while loadbalancing between two servers.

Comment: You want it to just redirect the browser to "/myapp"...? Or quietly prepend that to every path it passes to the backend?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot haproxy listens on port 8000 while it loadbalances between two jboss instances running application on port 8080. It should be easy for user to type the port number but not the full application path. "myapp" can have different contents and right now everything works except for ease of use for users who have to mémorise the http and port and path